# Antlr AST generating (possible) madness

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

Is the following even possible?  I want to "reverse" the input given to antlr and make each token a child of the previous one.

So, for the input (Assume each token is separated by the '.' char) :

```
Stack.Overflow.Horse
```

I would like my grammar to produce the following AST:

```
Horse
  |---Overflow
         |---Stack
```

So far, I've managed to reverse the nodes, but I'm unable to make them children of each other:

```
function
 : ID PERIOD function
   -> function ID
 | ID
 ;

ID  : 'a'..'z'*
    ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do that. You could make your rule like this:

```
function
 : ID PERIOD function
   -> ^(function ID)
 | ID
 ;
```

but that only makes the last node the root and all other nodes its children. For example, the following source:

```
a.b.c.d.e
```

will result in the following tree:

```
    e
 / / \ \
d c   b a
```

I can't see an easy fix since when you first parse `a.b.c.d.e`, `a` will be the `ID` and `b.c.d.e` the recursive call to `function`:

```
a.b.c.d.e
| +-----+
|    |
|    `-----> function
|
`----------> ID
```

resulting in the fact that `b.c.d.e` will have `a` as its child. When then `b` becomes the `ID`, it too is added as a child next to `a`. In your case, `a` should be removed as a child and then added to the list of `b`'s children. But AFAIK, that is not possible in ANLTR (at least, not in a clean way inside the grammar).

---

**EDIT**

Okay, as a work-around I had something elegant in mind, but that didn't work as I had hoped. So, as a less elegant solution, you could match the `last` node as the root in your rewrite rule:

```
function
  :  (id '.')* last=id -> ^($last)
  ;
```

and then collect all possible preceding nodes (`children`) in a `List` using the `+=` operator:

```
function
  :  (children+=id '.')* last=id -> ^($last)
  ;
```

and use a custom member-method in the parser to "inject" these `children` into the root of your tree (going from right to left in your `List`!):

```
function
  :  (children+=id '.')* last=id {reverse($children, (CommonTree)$last.tree);} -> ^($last)
  ;
```

A little demo:

```
grammar ReverseTree;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
}

@members {
  private void reverse(List nodes, CommonTree root) {
    if(nodes == null) return;
    for(int i = nodes.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      CommonTree temp = (CommonTree)nodes.get(i);
      root.addChild(temp);
      root = temp;
    }
  }
}

parse
  :  function+ EOF -> ^(ROOT function+)
  ;

function
  :  (children+=id '.')* last=id {reverse($children, (CommonTree)$last.tree);} -> ^($last)
  ;

id 
  :  ID
  ;

ID
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
  ;

Space
  :  ' ' {skip();}
  ;
```

And a little test class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("a.b.c.d.e    Stack.Overflow.Horse    singleNode");
        ReverseTreeLexer lexer = new ReverseTreeLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ReverseTreeParser parser = new ReverseTreeParser(tokens);
        ReverseTreeParser.parse_return returnValue = parser.parse();
        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)returnValue.getTree();
        DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
        StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
        System.out.println(st);
    }
}
```

which will produce an AST that looks like:

[image]

- (image generated using http://graph.gafol.net)

For the input string:

```
"a.b.c.d.e    Stack.Overflow.Horse    singleNode"
```

Comment: Damn - After hours of playing with my grammar I was hoping I was just missing a '^' in some place :(

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of alternate routes I could explore?  Different parser tools etc?

Comment: You sir, are a powerful man.  That worked great :) Thank you very much for your efforts.

Comment: @all, there _is_ proper solution using ANTLR's tree operators, see Sam's reply in this ANTLR mailing list answer: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/6brfxlzjw2hg6w6v